# Move sub-site to another site collection

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, permissions, content-migration

We have a SharePoint 2013 on premise environment.

I need to move some sub sites (spweb's) and their content, including the unique permissions, over to another site collection.

I have not found suitable powershell or GUI commands I can apply for my purpose. Is this possible with powershell or SharePoint GUI? Or do I have to use a 3rd party tool? Please advice.

If you know about any good tools I can use then please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have the unique Permission then I think best option is use the 3rd party tools i.e Sharegate( as they offer free trial).

There are limitation with export & import web commands.Even you use Includesecurity in your paramters then unique permission on list will not carry.I would try the following steps and test what moved and what's not.

1. [export](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) the subsite using the `Export-SPWeb http://site -Path "site export.cmp"`
2. [Create a subsite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607579.aspx) on the destination without template `New-SPWeb http://somesite/subweb1`
3. Now run the `Import-SPWeb http://site -Path export.cmp -IncludeUserSecurity -`Overwrite